# How to zero-normalize a molten dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

Let's say I have this molten data.frame

```
molten <- data.frame(
  gene = c("a1", "b1", "a1", "b1", "a1", "b1"),
  count = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7),
  condition = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
)
#   gene count condition
# 1   a1     3         A
# 2   b1     4         A
# 3   a1     5         B
# 4   b1     2         B
# 5   a1     6         C
# 6   b1     7         C
```

Which looks like this unmolten

```
molten %>% 
  dcast(gene ~ condition, value.var = "count")
#   gene A B C
# 1   a1 3 5 6
# 2   b1 4 2 7
```

How can I subtract column A from all the other numeric columns (B and C in this example). I want the final output to be molten, but I don't know if this can be done directly, or if I have to unmelt, subtract, and then melt. The final output should look like this:

```
#   gene A B C
# 1   a1 0 2 3
# 2   b1 0 -2 3
```

**Update:**

I'm also interested in a more complex scenario:

```
molten <- data.frame(
  gene = c("a1", "b1", "a1", "b1", "a1", "b1"),
  count = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7),
  condition = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
  day = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2)
)
```

The solution proposed by @eipi10 gives an error:

```
molten %>% 
  group_by(gene, condition) %>%
  mutate(count = count - count[day == 0])
Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
```

This is my workaround:

```
x <- list(a1 = 3, b1 = 4)
molten %>% 
  group_by(gene, condition) %>%
  mutate(count = count - x[[gene]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

molten %>% group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(count = count - count[condition=="A"])

    gene count condition
  (fctr) (dbl)    (fctr)
1     a1     0         A
2     b1     0         A
3     a1     2         B
4     b1    -2         B
5     a1     3         C
6     b1     3         C
```

**UPDATE:** To answer your comment, in your second example, you group by `gene` and `condition`. Then you want to subtract the value of `count` for `day==0`. But `day` equals zero only when `condition=="A"`. For `condition` "B" or "C" there's never a row where `day==0`. Here's what happens in an example where we do the subsetting ourselves:

```
m = molten

x = m$count[m$gene=="a1" & m$condition=="B"]
```

> x
>   [1] 5

```
y = m$count[m$gene=="a1" & m$condition=="B" & m$condition=="A"]
```

> y
>   numeric(0)

`numeric(0)` is a numeric vector of length zero. Since `x=5` and `y=numeric(0)` and we want `x - y`, we've asked R to return the result of `5 - numeric(0)`.

```
5 - numeric(0)
```

> numeric(0)

```
length(numeric(0))
```

> [1] 0

`mutate` is expecting the calculation to return a vector of length equal to either the number of rows in the group (1 in this case) or 1, but the length of the returned value was zero, causing the error.

I'm not exactly sure why `5 - numeric(0)` returns `numeric(0)` while, for example, `sum(numeric(0), 5)` returns 5. Maybe there's a good reason for this, or maybe it's just one of those enchanting quirks that keep R programmers on their toes. In any case, the error is good here, because it helps us realize us that there's actually no value to subtract when `condition != "A"` and that our code is therefore not doing what we thought it was.

Comment: I'm getting an error using a more complex input matrix (see updated question). Could you help me understand why I'm getting it or how to solve it?

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your answer. Do you see a workaround?

Comment: Never mind. I added my workaround, let me know if you know a better way

Answer (score 1):

```
require(reshape2)
require(magrittr)

subtract_num <- function(x, colname){
  ind = which(sapply(x, is.numeric))
  x[ind] = sapply(x[ind], subtract, x[colname])
  x
}

molten %>% 
  dcast(gene ~ condition, value.var = "count") %>% 
  subtract_num("A")
```

Result:

```
  gene A  B C
1   a1 0  2 3
2   b1 0 -2 3
```

P.S.: Seams like i understood the desired output very different than @eipi10

Comment: The OP said he wanted the final output to be molten, so I kept it in long format. Also, it looks like you need to fix the column names.

Comment: @eipi10, thx: fixed the names. Lets see which one he accepts ;)

Comment: Thank you both, I chose @eipi10's answer because it prevents me from having to dcast and melt again