# Why do NA==NULL , NULL==NULL print logical(0)?

Tags: r, null, na

Why does `NA==NULL`  result in `logical (0)` instead of FALSE?

And why does `NULL==NULL` result in `logical(0)` instead of TRUE?

Comment: does my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 8):

`NULL` is a "zero-length" object, so any elementwise comparison or operation with `NULL` will have length zero: `logical(0)` represents a logical vector of length zero.  You might find `identical()` useful: `identical(NULL,NULL)` is TRUE, `identical(NULL,NA)` is FALSE. Also see `?is.null`, `?is.na` for testing for the special values of `NA` and `NULL`.

See also: [Compare a value to null. Why is this true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774483/compare-a-value-to-null-why-is-this-true)

@Dason points out that `==` does elementwise comparison; when you do elementwise operations on vectors of two different lengths, R typically "recycles" the shorter vector to be equal in length to the longer one (with a warning if the lengths are not evenly divisible), but the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules) says

> As from R 1.4.0, any arithmetic operation involving a zero-length vector has a zero-length result.

Comment: Just to slightly add to the answer - it's useful to remember that == does element-wise comparison. So if you use it to compare two vectors that have length 5; you will get a length 5 vector back.

Comment: yes.  The slightly weird thing is that if you compare vectors of two different *non-zero* lengths, the shorter one is replicated to the length of the longer one. Admittedly it's impossible to replicate a zero-length vector to a positive length, but it's an edge case whose logic I have trouble explicitly justifying ...

Comment: `5 + numeric(0)` returns `numeric(0)`, but `sum(5, numeric(0))` returns `5`. Does this make sense or is this behavior inconsistent? When I saw your answer, I remembered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350139/496488) I wrote a few years ago where this issue came up (see the last paragraph) and I wasn't sure why.

Comment: I think it's consistent with the R language definition statement above. `+` is an arithmetic operation/operator, `sum()` is a function ... `sum()` *combines* all of its elements (e.g. `sum(5:7,10)` is 28) rather than computing elementwise.

Comment: "`NULL` is a 'zero-length' object" is also demonstrated by  `as.numeric(NULL)` OR `as.character(NULL)` OR `as.logical(NULL)`